# I am facing problem to execute foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to execute foreach loop but it doesn't show any value on HTML form.
Here is code.

```
function displayOptions($options){
foreach($options as $option){
    printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>",strtolower($option),ucwords($option));
}}
```

Here is a array..

```
$fruits=["mango","apple","orange","banana","coconut"];
```

Here is an HTML Code.

```
<select name="fruits" id="fruits">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Select Some Fruits</option>
     <?php displayOptions($fruits);?>
</select>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: if you had `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script, you would have gotten an undefined function error for `ucword()`. It should be `ucwords()`

Comment: also you should be having `echo` as in `<?php echo displayOptions($fruits);?>`

Comment: vote to close as typo

Comment: Thank you @Akintunde-Rotimi I got it. It's a typo mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in the function code. A typo actually.

Change `ucword($option)` to `ucwords($option)` and it would work.

Also, Make sure the function implementation or signature is before the its execution.

Comment: Thanks @Mani It's type mistake. I got it